# How to render a component using onPress()?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'd like to render / navigate to a new component passing props to it once I click on a button.

**First attempt** - syntax is wrong

```
{
  this.state.history ? (
    this.state.history.map(data => {
      return (
        <View style={styles.historyUnit}>
          <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={return <Map2 latitude={data1} longitude={data1} />;}
          >
            {" "}
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    })
  ) : (
    <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
  );
}
```

**Second attempt** - component is not rendered

```
onPress={this.showHistory}
```

```
  showHistoryUnit = (data1, data2) => {
    return <Map2 latitude={data1} longitude={data1} />;
  };
```

**Third attempt** - I navigate to the component, but props are not passed

```
  showHistoryUnit = (data1, data2) => {
    this.props.navigation("map2")
    return <Map2 latitude={data1} longitude={data1} />;
  };
```

How can I make this happen?

Comment: Do you want to render the `Map2` component on the same screen/route once the you press?

Comment: What do you use for navigation?

Comment: ` onPress={return <Map2 latitude={data1} longitude={data1} />;}` this won't work you set the local state true false based on onPress and render it where ever it requires

Comment: do you want to navigate to a different screen on button Press?

Comment: @UmairSarfraz yes, I think that would be the best for the user. But if there is another alternative I would try it.

Comment: @GauravRoy I'd like a map to appear showing the user a specific location that he is clicking on, but then he should be ablt to close it and go back to where he was. So I guess the answer is no, he should stay in the same screen.

Comment: @kenodek Im using react-navigation

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modals . try using modal then

Comment: @GauravRoy ok I'll try this

Comment: @Sundar I didn't really understand what you mean with local state true false

Comment: What's `data1` and `data2`? How are you accessing them?

Comment: @UmairSarfraz they are coords (latitude and longitude), I'm accesing them from my map() function.

Comment: do tell in case of any doubts.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.state = {
    selectedId = 0
}

this.state.history.map(data => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.historyUnit}>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({ selectedId: data.id })
                }}
            >
                {data.id === this.state.selectedId &&
                    <Map2 latitude={data1} longitude={data1} />
                }
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
})
```

it just returns a Map2 component in the same time.
if you want return Map2 in a row use array instead

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should use a modal or similar for displaying specific `Map` information but this can also be achieved using component internal state.

```
state = {
    mapComponent: null,
};

if (this.state.history) {
    return this.state.mapComponent || this.state.history.map(data => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.historyUnit}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => this.setState({ mapComponent: <Map2 latitude={data1} longitude={data1} /> })}
                >
                    {" "}
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View >
        );
    })
}

return <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a ternary operator with setState
Like when you onPress in a button set some state and then use ternary operator to show the view
check your `this.state.history` ideally, it should be a boolean.